# can't select the objects but 3D cursor move

Tags: objects, object-mode

I have the problem about select objects. When I try to select them, it doesn't work but 3D cursor looks moving (Im not in 3D cursor mode). This problem happened sometime, but works good all of sudden (and doesn't work also)...
If someone know how to solve this, let me know please.

Comment: most likely your Blender preferences are on "right click select". Either change that or use a right click to select your object.

Comment: It works well !! Thank you so much for  resolving the problems.